# Loop through Circular list Java

Tags: java, circular-list

I want to create a method that loops though a circular linked list, Essentially mimicking a token ring network. I create a random number of either 0 or 1, if it is 0, it deletes the first item in the list. If it is one it just says they are still logged on.

So i should have something like this..

User A Logged on
User B logged off
User A logged off

When list is clear it terminates

The problem is it seems to always leave one particular user....How can I make this work?

```
public void log(){
        if(start==null)
            System.out.println("List is empty..");
        else{
        Node temp=start;

        System.out.print("->");
        //get rid of each user with a similar method but with a random user removed....
        while(temp.next!=null && count>0)
        {



            int  r = rand.nextInt(2);

            if(r==0)
            {

                deleteAt(0);
                System.out.println(" OFF"+temp.data);



            }

            else if(r==1)
            {
                   System.out.println(" ON "+temp.data);


            }
            temp=temp.next;
        }
                //System.out.println(counter);

    }
}

    public void deleteFirst() {
        Node temp=start;
        while(temp.next!=start){
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    temp.next=start.next;
    start=start.next;
    count--;
}




   public void deleteAt(int position){
       Node current=start;
       Node previous=start;

      for(int i=0;i<position;i++){
        if(current.next==start)
            break;
        previous=current;
        current=current.next;
    }

    if(position==0)
        deleteFirst();
    else
        previous.next=current.next;
    count--;
}
```

Comment: probably should validate if there's one item left, since temp = temp.next referencing itself gives me a headache thinking about it.

Comment: Would that not just essentially set temp to what is already in temp? Not good practice but wouldn't affect the program, am I wrong?

Comment: How does your `deleteAt()` method re-assign `next`?  In particular, when you get down to a one-item list, does it make `lastItem.next = lastItem`?

Comment: @user3020002 it depends on how your deleteAt() method works.  Please post that.  circular references are a pain sometimes.

Comment: I have added my delete methods, one for delete any and another if it is the first in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the last element from a circular linked list is a special case, because you need to set start to null. So you need to cater for that in your delete routines: test whether `start->next == start`.

Besides that, looping through the list while deleting elements requires special care: temp in the outer loop in log() can point to the removed element, rather than an element in the list. Taking `temp=temp->next` then may not be valid.

Also, count is decremented twice in deleteAt(0).